# Image resizing performance comparison

Tags: php, gd, benchmarking

I'm saving two photos from an upload. One is a larger photo and the other is a thumb.

I was wondering if i used less resources to create the thumb copy of a photo from the reduced larger photo say 450*400 or create the thumb from the original that can be say 3mb and say 2500px * whatever or is it 6 one way or a half dozen another?

```
imagecopyresampled($photo, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photo_width, $photo_height, $width, $height);

imagecopyresampled($thumb_photo, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height); // old way

imagecopyresampled($thumb_photo, $photo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $photo_width, $photo_height); // new way
```

Comment: What? Can you rephrase that second paragraph?

Comment: @RyanNaddy from what i get he's asking if its better to load two images or to resize the bigger one to make the thumb!

Comment: If it's memory use you are worried about http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php and http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php are your friends, experiment and find out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take much more memory to load a 2500x2500 image into memory than a 450x400. Like, +30x more.

On the other hand, if you're already loading it then you can reuse it with no additional memory usage (besides what's required to make the actual third image).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to reuse the resized image to create the thumb, but only if you remove the original from memory:

```
imagecopyresampled($photo, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photo_width, $photo_height, $width, $height);

imagedestroy($source);

imagecopyresampled($thumb_photo, $photo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $photo_width, $photo_height);
```